# Tag for redundant/useless code/definitions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there some tag, that I'm not finding for talking about case where you find code you think is redundant or useless and want to discuss it / question whether it is actually useful or not?

If not - is this intentional (e.g. burnination) or just happenstance?

Comment: I think you could ask about this on [codereview.se]. Best to read their rules first.

Comment: I don't think such question can be made on-topic on SO as essentially you'd be asking for guesses that can't be independently validated... As side effect there is no such tag.

Comment: you mean a tag or tags here on meta? discussion, debug, or mcve together with specific-question would probably be reasonable.

Comment: That feels like a meta tag, it isn't really about the code but about what you want to do with it.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery: It's about case where _other_ people's code doesn't seem to do anything and you want to know whether that's true or whether you've misunderstood. So definitely not a meta-issue.

Answer (score 0):

"is this code useless/redundant" - there is no such tag.

It is unlikely to be created because:

- That feels like a meta tag, it isn't really about the code but about what you want to do with it. (from comment by [John Montgomery](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7496073/john-montgomery))
- such question usually can't be made on-topic on SO as essentially you'd be asking for list of guesses that can't be independently validated.

In rare cases such question may be made on-topic on SO if you roughly know why code is there to start with, something like:

> c# - is `stream.Close()` before end of `using` block for that stream useful for regular streams in similar way I've seen for `MemoryStream` used to obtain byte  content of memory stream. In particular can anything be done with `stream` between `.Close` and closing brace of the `using` block.

Even in such case regular language + framework tags would be enough.

Note that there is specific subset of these problems that has its own [unreachable-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unreachable-code) but those problems are detected by a compiler and always have a concrete "easy" to validate answer (one essentially needs to know particular language specification by heart but that does not require guessing).

Comment: Nope, it is about the actual code. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59693300/do-make-cudaextent-make-cudapitchedptr-make-cudapos-do-anything-special).

Comment: @einpoklum this question is deeply based in how CUDA works. Let's assume somebody is really profficient with the "redundant code" tag in context of CUDA - would they be able to answer *any* question about *any* redundant code in *any* language? Compare to, say, `recursion` - one *could* answer about recursion in any language, as long as they are aware of the basics. A good answer doesn't even need actual code - it can be in pseudo-code or just an explanation, as the concept is, for the most part, language agnostic. Whether some call is equivalent to another call in a language is not.

Comment: @VLAZ: "would they be able to answer any question about any redundant code in any language?" <- No, but - so what? Tags intersect. Consider the "idiomatic" tag. Can anyone answer questions about what's idiomatic in _all_ languages/frameworks/environments?